# How to turn off auto commit and give explicit commit usign @transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I turn off auto commit and give explicit commit using `@transactional`?

I have multiple operations and I want them to get committed after all select and update are done. Reason being the select is done based on some field as null and this data is used somewhere and then update is done to some records. So before new records come, I have to change the field as to some value and avoid selection of new data i.e select only those record that got updated

Comment: are u using JDBC template or ...?

Comment: I am using JPARepository for db operations

Comment: So u mean if i have 10 update operation in the cmethod annotated with it,all the update will be committed at once and not one by one right ? Also what if i want to keep the auto commit off and explicitly perform commit after last update operation ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but be noted that @transnational also committed at  once at end of method and not one by one.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put the @Transaction annotation around all the work you want to be committed:

```
@Autowired
private Manager1 manager1;

@Autowired
private Manager2 manager2;

@Transactional
public void doStuff() {
   manager1.do();
   manager2.do();
}
```

Everything in method doStuff() will all be committed together, unless there is an exception thrown, in which case it will all be rolled back.

Comment: Do u mean @Transaction-al annotation ?

Comment: Thanks.But what if i want to off auto commit and do it explicitly ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Let Spring do the work for you, especially for these "cross-cutting" concerns. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Programmatic approach for this case.

**Programmatic transaction management:** This means that you have manage the transaction with the help of programming. That gives you extreme flexibility, but it is difficult to maintain. 
Vs
**Declarative transaction management:** This means you separate transaction management from the business code. You only use annotations or XML based configuration to manage the transactions.

Perhaps, alternative way for your questions by Programmatic transaction management.
Eg.

```
/** DataSourceTransactionManager */
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager txManager;

    public void yourMethod() {
    try {

         // Start a manual transaction.
         TransactionStatus status = getTransactionStatus();

         your code...
         .....
         .....

        //your condition 
        txManager.commit(status);
        //your condition 
        txManager.rollback(status);

         } catch (YourException e) {
        //your condition 
        txManager.rollback(status);

        }       
    }    

/**
     * getTransactionStatus
     *
     * @return TransactionStatus
     */
    private TransactionStatus getTransactionStatus() {
        DefaultTransactionDefinition dtd = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        dtd.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        dtd.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
        dtd.setReadOnly(false);

        return txManager.getTransaction(dtd);
    }
```

**Note:** It does not mean you need to always use one approach like Programmatic transaction management. I prefer mixed approach. Please use easy way like Declarative transaction for simple database services, otherwise, just control with Programmatic transaction in your services will save your logic easily.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-commit default mode it true.

In the case of a Transaction on a method, **it will override the auto-commit setting for that method(if auto-commit is on default mode)**. This means Transaction will set auto-commit false and queries executed within the method will be part of the same transaction.

But When you explicitly set auto-commit to true, you are telling Hibernate that you want to control when transactions are committed. And in this case, if needs to use the @Transacional method then you have to set auto-commit=false manually everywhere used in the transaction otherwise cause an exception Caused by: `java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true`

So, I think it would be much better directly delete a set of auto-commit. and just use the default mode unless use auto-commit=false mode.